# sed extract CN out of ldap_access_filter in sssd.conf

Tags: unix, sed

I have the definition of `ldap_access_filter` in `sssd.conf` and for some reporting purpose, I need to extract `CN`s (Group Names) out of this filter defined.

`ldap_access_filter` is as below

```
ldap_access_filter = (|(msSFU30PosixMemberOf=CN=grp1,OU=UNIX,OU=Security Groups,OU=Groups,OU=Corp,DC=my,DC=domain,DC=com)(msSFU30PosixMemberOf=CN=grp2,OU=UNIX,OU=Security Groups,OU=Groups,OU=Corp,DC=my,DC=domain,DC=com)(msSFU30PosixMemberOf=CN=grp3,OU=UNIX,OU=Security Groups,OU=Groups,OU=Corp,DC=my,DC=domain,DC=com)(msSFU30PosixMemberOf=CN=grp4,OU=UNIX,OU=Security Groups,OU=Groups,OU=Corp,DC=my,DC=domain,DC=com)(msSFU30PosixMemberOf=CN=grp5,OU=UNIX,OU=Security Groups,OU=Groups,OU=Corp,DC=my,DC=domain,DC=com))
```

Output I want is

```
grp1, grp2, grp3, grp4, grp5
```

or

```
grp1 grp2 grp3 grp4 grp5
```

How can I use the `sed` to get this output.

I am new to `sed` or reg-exp.  Please help me out

Answer (score 0):

While it is certainly possible to do this with `sed`, you can get a clean solution with `grep` and `awk`.

```
 grep -o 'CN=\w+' Input.txt  | awk -F= '{print $2}'
```

Answer (score 0):

With awk:

```
awk -F"=|," '{while (++i<=NF){if($i~/CN/){print $(i+1)}}}' InputFile
```

Setting the field seperatots as `=` and `,`. Then check if the current field is `CN`, if yes then print the next field, which will be the `group name`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an `gnu awk` (due to multiple Characters in RS)

```
awk -vRS="CN=" -F, 'NR>1{printf "%s ",$1}END {print ""}' file
grp1 grp2 grp3 grp4 grp5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this sed command also

```
sed -e 's/CN=\([^,]\+\)/:\1:/g'  -e 's/[^:]\+.\([^:]*\)./\1 /g' FileName
```

**Output :**

```
grp1 grp2 grp3 grp4 grp5
```

Answer (score 0):

Noticed your filter has (data)(data )(data )(data )(data )..you can also match each CN group and take their values from each of the five group

**example**

```
sed '/ldap_access_filter/s/.*(.*=CN=\([[:alnum:]]*\).*)(.*=CN=\([[:alnum:]]*\).*)(.*=CN=\([[:alnum:]]*\).*)(.*=CN=\([[:alnum:]]*\).*)(.*=CN=\([[:alnum:]]*\).*)/\1, \2, \3, \4, \5/g'
```

**results from the above command line**

```
grp1, grp2, grp3, grp4, grp5
```

since your filter is in a file, this piece `/ldap_access_filter/` will look for the line that contain `ldap_access_filter` (this will only target your filter).

for each group this

```
(.*=CN=\([[:alnum:]]*\).*)
```

is repeated in the command line above 5 times to extract the value from the 5 groups